# Freemarker - unable to get variable to increase in value

Tags: variables, freemarker

I've been trying for several hours to get some freemarker code to output what I want. Essentially I'm trying to get it to grab a particular "attribute" from a product which defines the total cost for something. With that number - multiply it by the quantity of that item ordered, and then subtract the amount already paid. Ultimately I'm trying to calculate this for each of the items ordered, add those numbers together to come up with a remaining balance due.

```
                <#list order.items as orderItem>
            <#list orderItem.attributes as attribute>
                    <#if "${attribute.name}" == ("Total Cost")> 
                        <#assign subtotal=orderItem.subtotal?keep_after("$")>                       
                        <#assign total += (attribute.value?number * orderItem.quantity?number - subtotal?number)>
                </#if>
            </#list>
        </#list>
         Total:  ${total}
```

When I run this, my variable is null (because I don't officially get to see any error output, I'm assuming this means that I'm getting an error).
My original problems originated from the defined variables (orderItem.subtotal) being listed as a string with a dollar sign in it, so I had to set it to remove that and then use it as a number. The attribute.value is always a number but treated like a string. orderItem.quantity is a number.
I tried using this as well:

```
                    <#list order.items as orderItem>
            <#list orderItem.attributes as attribute>
                    <#if "${attribute.name}" == ("Total Cost")> 
                        <#assign subtotal=orderItem.subtotal?keep_after("$")>                       
                        <#assign total ++ (attribute.value?number * orderItem.quantity?number - subtotal?number)>
                </#if>
            </#list>
        </#list>
         Total:  ${total}
```

With the ++ expression, It was even worse and caused my entire template to be blank when generated, rather than just that variable.

Am I doing something wrong here? I cant seem to get this variable to increment to get this total printed out on my templates.

Comment: `<#if "${attribute.name}" == ("Total Cost")>` you are comparing strings right? `<#if attribute.name == "Total Cost">` will do. You should define total before your #list, in case that loop don't run, you will at least see something that tells you total did not change. If you have access to server log, you can see errors there. If you are running tomcat locally, you should have access to log/console output for server

Comment: "When I run this, my variable is null " which variable is null? Please post how `order.item` is defined, you can also somewhat debug some of this by putting if statements at places and print out some messages so at the least you know which statements are failing

Comment: @Huangism - how do you suggest I define "total" before my list? I've tried both assign and local and when I do that before the list there is some sort of error and my entire output ends up blank (assuming its because of an error).
The variable that is null is "total" when I run my first set. Order.Item is defined by the Ecwid storefront as the items that were ordered.

Comment: `<#assign total=0 />` should work. if there is an error, you need to read the log and see what error it is. If your total is 0 after you run the code then you know it probably did not go thru the list for some reason. You can also just output stuff on the page to see if values from the variables you have are what you expect them to be

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that you don't see the error messages. It's much harder to work with any language like that. If you can't make the developers fix that, there's a trick. Put the piece of template you are working on in place of the `Your actual template comes here!` below, and now you will see the error message:

```
<#attempt>
<#assign myTemplate><#noparse>
Your actual template comes here!
</#noparse></#assign>
<@myTemplate?interpret />
<#recover>
  <p>Template error:
  <pre>
  ${.error}
  </pre>
</#attempt>
```

This only while you develop the template of course; don't leave it there like this after that.

As of you 2nd sample, there's no such thing as `<#assign total ++ otherStuff>`, so that's a parsing error (that you don't see). (Check the FreeMarker Manual when in doubt.)

Also, give the bad circumstances, you may find this service handy:
https://try.freemarker.apache.org

Comment: I tried putting your template in mine and putting the problem set of language in where you said and when it compiles nothing is output, not sure what the problem is there. As for '<#assign total ++ otherStuff>' I did lots of research to come to the conclusion of trying to use that and there were several places in my research that said using ++ is more what I want in this case. Does that not exist in Freemarker? Its shown as an assignment operator in the Freemarker Manual.

Comment: You mean putting your template into mine, I guess. Very strange. As your template is between `<#noparse>` and `</#noparse>`, parsing exceptions should be postponed till run time. Do you have output before and after the `#attempt`, that also should be visible, yet isn't shown either?

Comment: As of the `++` operator, yes it's supported, but you should use `+=` in your case. See here: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_assignment

Comment: Everything before and after #attempt works fine, it was just anything put in that attemp template you gave me. There was no output. It is odd, but I don't have control over the web servers producing this content so I'm not really able to see what the problem is with that.

Comment: That could only mean that what you put in place of `Your actual template comes here!` doesn't fail, it just doesn't print anything.

Comment: Well, I've actually put in there just some plain text to output so that I know that it worked and it still was just all blank in between #attempt

Comment: That's very strange. I have no idea how could that happen. You put your piece in place of `Your actual template comes here!`, and don't change anything else, right?

Answer (score 0):

This code should help:

```
[#assign orderItems = [
{
"name":"prod1",
"price":"$1,000.99",
"quantity":"2"
},
{
"name":"prod2",
"price":"$10.00",
"quantity":"3"
},
{
"name":"prod3",
"price":"$20.00",
"quantity":"3"
}
]]
[#assign total = 0]

<br>Total on start: ${total}
[#list orderItems as orderItem]
    <br>Adding cost of ${orderItem.name} (price: ${orderItem.price}, qty: ${orderItem.quantity})
    [#assign total += orderItem.quantity?number * orderItem.price?keep_after("$")?replace(",","")?number]
    <br>total: ${total}
[/#list]
<br>Final total: ${total}
```

Output:

```
Total on start: 0 
Adding cost of prod1 (price: $1,000.99, qty: 2) 
total: 2,001.98 
Adding cost of prod2 (price: $10.00, qty: 3) 
total: 2,031.98 
Adding cost of prod3 (price: $20.00, qty: 3) 
total: 2,091.98 
Final total: 2,091.98
```